# Установка cmake на Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cmake, openssl

скачал cmake с официального сайта, устанавливаю по гайду
Выдает ошибку
./bootstrap
Использую Ubuntu 19.04

```
CMake 3.19.4, Copyright 2000-2020 Kitware, Inc. and Contributors
Found GNU toolchain
C compiler on this system is: gcc
C++ compiler on this system is: g++
Makefile processor on this system is: make
g++ has setenv
g++ has unsetenv
g++ does not have environ in stdlib.h
g++ has stl wstring
g++ has <ext/stdio_filebuf.h>
---------------------------------------------
make: «cmake» не требует обновления.
loading initial cache file /home/user/cmake-3.19.4/Bootstrap.cmk/InitialCacheFlags.cmake
-- Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR)
CMake Error at Utilities/cmcurl/CMakeLists.txt:505 (message):
Could not find OpenSSL. Install an OpenSSL development package or
configure CMake with -DCMAKE_USE_OPENSSL=OFF to build without OpenSSL.
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Хотя openssl стоит

```
openssl version -a
OpenSSL 1.1.1b 26 Feb 2019
built on: Wed Apr 3 10:50:23 2019 UTC
platform: debian-amd64
options: bn(64,64) rc4(16x,int) des(int) blowfish(ptr)
compiler: gcc -fPIC -pthread -m64 -Wa,--noexecstack -Wall -Wa,--noexecstack -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/openssl-uEA50R/openssl-1.1.1b=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DRC4_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DX25519_ASM -DPADLOCK_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DNDEBUG -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/lib/ssl"
ENGINESDIR: "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/engines-1.1"
Seeding source: os-specific
```

Первое же решение в интернете говорит сделать так

```
sudo apt install libssl-dev
```

Но мне не помогает:

```
 sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
E: Невозможно найти пакет libssl-dev
```

---

Тоже не помогает

sudo apt update; sudo apt install cmake

```
Сущ:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Игн:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease                          
Ошб:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security Release                            
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Игн:4 http://by.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease
Игн:5 http://by.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease
Игн:6 http://by.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports InRelease
Ошб:7 http://by.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 82.209.230.71 80]
Ошб:8 http://by.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 82.209.230.71 80]
Ошб:9 http://by.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 82.209.230.71 80]
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
E: Репозиторий «http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security Release» больше не содержит файла Release.
N: Обновление из этого репозитория нельзя выполнить безопасным способом, поэтому по умолчанию он отключён.
N: Информацию о создании репозитория и настройках пользователя смотрите в справочной странице apt-secure(8).
E: Репозиторий «http://by.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco Release» не содержит файла Release.
N: Обновление из этого репозитория нельзя выполнить безопасным способом, поэтому по умолчанию он отключён.
N: Информацию о создании репозитория и настройках пользователя смотрите в справочной странице apt-secure(8).
E: Репозиторий «http://by.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates Release» не содержит файла Release.
N: Обновление из этого репозитория нельзя выполнить безопасным способом, поэтому по умолчанию он отключён.
N: Информацию о создании репозитория и настройках пользователя смотрите в справочной странице apt-secure(8).
E: Репозиторий «http://by.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports Release» не содержит файла Release.
N: Обновление из этого репозитория нельзя выполнить безопасным способом, поэтому по умолчанию он отключён.
N: Информацию о создании репозитория и настройках пользователя смотрите в справочной странице apt-secure(8).
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Пакет cmake недоступен, но упомянут в списке зависимостей другого
пакета. Это может означать, что пакет отсутствует, устарел или
доступен из источников, не упомянутых в sources.list

E: Для пакета «cmake» не найден кандидат на установку
```

Comment: `sudo apt update; sudo apt install cmake`

Comment: Используется убунта 19.04, которая уже почти месяу как не поддерживается... Вот и удаляют репы. Обновляйтесь на свежую или используйте подходящий LTS.

Comment: подскажите как это сделать, я пытаюсь по гайдам, у меня не получается, при обновлении пишет
Ошб:5 http://by.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco Release                           
  404  Not Found [IP: 82.209.230.71 80]
Игн:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease                  
Ошб:7 http://by.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 82.209.230.71 80]
Ошб:8 http://by.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 82.209.230.71 80]